# Table cell on click add row just under

Tags: jquery, html-table, append, closest

I have a table this way:

```
                <div class="table-wrapper">
                    <table id="HK_myTable">
                    <tr>
                        <th style="width:0.5%"></th>
                        <th style="width:2%">STORE</th>
                        <th style="width:10%">SECTION</th>
                        <th style="width:30%">ELEMENT</th>
                        <th style="width:48.5%">ACTION</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td><a class="icon fa fa-trash" onclick="is_done($(this))"></a></td>
                    <td>2227</td>
                    <td>BATHROOM</td>
                    <td>CABIN GLAS</td>
                    <td>NEED REPARATION</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
```

I want when I click on the first cell of each row I create a new row just under the clicked one. Here is my JS Code:

```
                    function is_done(row)
                        {
                        var currentdate = new Date(); 
                        var tm = currentdate.getDate() + "/"
                                    + (currentdate.getMonth()+1)  + "/" 
                                    + currentdate.getFullYear() + " "  
                                    + currentdate.getHours() + ":"  
                                    + currentdate.getMinutes();                 
                        row.closest('td').html('Maintenance');  //This works                    
                        row.closest('tr').append('<tr><td>checked on'+tm+'<td></tr>');  //Here is the problem.. no row is added under the clicked <td>                          
                        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to switch 2 lines of code:

From:

```
row.closest('td').html('Maintenance');
row.closest('tr').after('<tr><td>checked on' + tm + '<td></tr>');
```

To:

```
row.closest('tr').after('<tr><td>checked on' + tm + '<td></tr>');
row.closest('td').html('Maintenance');
```

When you run `row.closest('td').html('Maintenance');` you change the html and the object of `row`

*Please Note:* You have an unclosed `<td>` at the end `<tr></table>`, Also user `.after()` and not `.append()`

**Demo**

```js
function is_done(row) {
  var currentdate = new Date();
  var tm = currentdate.getDate() + "/" +
    (currentdate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" +
    currentdate.getFullYear() + " " +
    currentdate.getHours() + ":" +
    currentdate.getMinutes();
  row.closest('tr').after('<tr><td>checked on' + tm + '<td></tr>');
  row.closest('td').html('Maintenance');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table-wrapper">
  <table id="HK_myTable">
    <tr>
      <th style="width:0.5%"></th>
      <th style="width:2%">STORE</th>
      <th style="width:10%">SECTION</th>
      <th style="width:30%">ELEMENT</th>
      <th style="width:48.5%">ACTION</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a class="icon fa fa-trash" onclick="is_done($(this))">click</a>
      </td>
      <td>2227</td>
      <td>BATHROOM</td>
      <td>CABIN GLAS</td>
      <td>NEED REPARATION</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: @karmel No problem, happy to help